# Using two audio inputs as separate lines with Realtek ALC886 sound card on CentOS

Tags: linux, audio, centos, driver, alsa

I'm trying to use (Recording with gstreamer) two audio inputs in parallel on CentOS with Realtek ALC886 sound card.

I can record each of them separately (not at the same time) by setting each of them to be the default device in the OS.

On Windows I can do it by choosing the separate all input jacks as independent input devices option:

[image: separate all input jacks as independent input devices on windows]

But on linux the Relatek driver is outdated (hasn't been updated since 2014):

[image]

I tried to use the [PulseAudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) for it and that didn't work.

running "arecord -l" gives this output:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC886 Analog [ALC886 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC886 Alt Analog [ALC886 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

output of "amixer scontents" is:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Front Left: Capture 11832 [18%] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 11832 [18%] [on]
```

Comment: Is this a programming question? Anyway, show the output of `arecord -l` and `amixer scontents`.

Comment: output is in edited question

Comment: You have two independent capture devices, "Analog" and "Alt Analog". You must to configure PulseAudio correctly, but that is not programming related.